# How to create dynamic formGroup in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying this for the first time to create dynamic formgroup in Angular reactive forms.

I have an API call and I am getting response object. Based on object name key I want to create a `FormGroup` name.

Example:-

```
[
 {
  "LicenseName": "Shop license",
  "LicenseTypeID": "D98B196D668"
 },
 {
  "LicenseName": "Product license",
  "LicenseTypeID": "B98L00D098"
 }
]
```

So I want to create dynamic formGroup with license name. Right now I am hard coding it.

```
this.Shoplicense = new FormGroup({
      LicenseNumber: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      DOE: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });

this.Productlicense = new FormGroup({
      LicenseNumber: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      DOE: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });

get shoplicenseInfo() {
    return this.Shoplicense.controls;
  }
  get productlicenseInfo() {
    return this.Productlicense.controls;
  }
```

Any other way to capture data into these form ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Meaning ? Didn't get you .

Comment: No, I want as many form group as object name if possible. If not then is there any other way ? I have different cards with same fieldname but forms are different as you can see from my question. So how will I bind this dynamically ?

Comment: @OptimistRohit Did you find out solution for this or still looking for it ?

Comment: @GRD I am still looking for it.

Comment: @GRD sure . you can

Comment: How would you like to connect formGroups with your template html ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zLo9s9M check this out, is this what you are looking for as shown in image, Each card represent separate fromGroup with its separate control @OptimistRohit

Comment: @GRD I will support you back. But your understanding is wrong. I have a json response of licenses with licenses ID and Name. Based on loop I am showing cards of licenses. Ok? Now under each card I have 2 fields only ie; licesnse number from user input and Date from mat datepicker. If User submit the first card/license only then it must send info to the first license group. My problem is I don't know how many licenses I will get from json. Each License should have each formgroup. All licenses cards are not mandotary to submit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240228/discussion-between-grd-and-optimist-rohit).

Answer (score 0):

Like with real arrays, you can only push onto an array. Therefore, add a FormArray to an FormGroup which will receive one FormControl per dataChunk from your API Call.

1. Create your FormGroup containing a FormArray

   ```
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
        licenses: new FormArray([])
    })
   ```
2. After receiving the data, store it into an Array

   ```
    const data: Array<{LicenseName: string, LicenseTypeID: string}> = [];
   ```
3. Iterate over your data, adding a FormControl per call

   ```
    data.forEach(dataChunk => this.formGroup.addControl(dataChunk.LicenseName, new FormControl(dataChunk.LicenseTypeID)))
   ```

Comment: Didn't get the 3rd point. How to will I add form control and validations on each group ? Also I need to store data from from form-control individually. Same I need to show in UI separate formgroup for each iterated cards.

Comment: Also I cannot hard code object like this inside and array. There might some more keys get added in future.

Comment: data in the third point is referred to the data returned by your api. Just iterate over the returned data and decide on each object separately what should happen. If some fields need validation and some not, then you must think of a way providing metadata for each object. Regarding your second comment, there is nothing hardcoded here, this is a type hint.